# No rows in sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats for a particluar stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, dmv

I am running DMV queries to get stats for my stored procedure, but I am not finding any rows against this SP under `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`.

Please suggest what could be various reason for this as I can see my stored procedure has been executed multiple times.

Comment: It doesn't have WITH RECOMPILE option int. There are 4 procedure gets executed by SSIS packages which runs for like 7 hrs all together and none of them is listed in DMV. I am not sure if there is heavy load on the server. Please suggest how to find this and if the plan is getting shunted out.

Answer (score 3):

> By using this DMV, you can returns metrics for stored procedures, but
>   it does not directly identify the stored procedure by name.  Instead,
>   the DMV only identifies the object_id, and a database_id for each
>   stored procedure:  Therefore to identify the actual stored procedure
>   name, that the performance figures belong to, you should either join
>   the output of this DMV with one of the system views within the
>   appropriate database, or use a few metadata functions

Therefore you should consider using `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` along with one you mentioned in you're question to get stats.

Also,

You can look in the plan cache to get a pretty good idea of stored procedure usage.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) Execution_count
 FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
 where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
   group by cp.plan_handle, DB_NAME(st.dbid),
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), 
   OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by max(cp.usecounts)
```

There are various other queries via which you can analyse the metrics for your stored procedures. [Monitoring stored procedure usage](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3687186/Monitoring-Stored-Procedure-Usage.htm)

Also, read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/tracking-stored-procedure-usage)

Comment: I am using sql server 2012 (SP1)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a Stored Procedure that did not show up in the dm_exec_procedure_stats view. No "WITH RECOMPILE" clause and I tried to DROP and CREATE the PROCEDURE again. New object_id but still missing from the dm_exec_procedure_stats view.

The SP is using a # temp table, and it actually also had a ALTER TABLE statement adding a few columns in the temp table.

I changed that so the temp table is initially created with all columns, and VIOLA ... it appeared in the dm_exec_procedure_stats view :)

So I think my approach with altering object during runtime may be the reason that an execution plan is not possible. Don't know but it worked :)

Comment: You are correct (ALTER TABLE). See [A Warning to Those Using sys.dm_exec_query_stats - Adam Machanic](https://dataeducation.com/a-warning-to-those-using-sys-dm_exec_query_stats/)